# Chromatic number of Kneser Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to show that the chromatic number of Kneser Graphs, $\chi(K(n,k)) \geq n -2k+2$. So far I know that the degree of each vertex in a Kneser Graph is given by $n-k \choose k$.

But, I don't know how to start off- I'm a little stuck. Any hints?

Comment: Well, to begin with, the thing you wrote is wrong; $\binom {n-k}k$ can be an upper bound on the chromatic number (by Brooks' theorem, except in a few special cases) but there is no reason to think it's a lower bound. To give a different example: in a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$, the degree of every vertex can go as high as you want, but the chromatic number is still $2$.

Comment: Oh yes that's so true thank you! I'll edit that out. Any suggestions on how to proceed with this question?

Comment: A similar question was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224832/critical-subgraph-of-the-kneser-graph?rq=1)

Comment: Most proofs that $\chi(K(n,k)\ge n-2k+2$ involve algebraic topology, I don't think there is an elementary proof.